# How do I melt a dataframe that includes pre-computed confidence intervals for plotting?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, reshape2, confidence-interval

I have the [a dataframe](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/88f76c7be8ade3a626f474f4857e16f8/stats.csv) that includes +/- confidence intervals. I assembled the dataset myself from secondary open datasets that only had +/- CIs, so there is not much that I can do. I understand that the quickest way to plot multiple series with `ggplot2` is to `reshape2` the dataframe, which I can easily do like

```
melt(df, id.vars = c("Year"))
```

except that that turns CI columns into proper series. Now, I'd eventually like to produce a plot like this.

[image]

which I produced with

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Total.inflow), color="red") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Total.inflow-Total.inflow.CI, ymax = Total.inflow+Total.inflow.CI), colour="red", fill="red", alpha=0.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = EU.inflow), color="blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = EU.inflow-EU.inflow.CI, ymax = EU.inflow+EU.inflow.CI), colour="blue", fill="blue", alpha=0.1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = ROW.inflow), color="green") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ROW.inflow-ROW.inflow.CI, ymax = ROW.inflow+ROW.inflow.CI), colour="green", fill="green", alpha=0.1)
```

Ideas?

---

**WORKING SOLUTION**

Thanks to @lukeA for pointing me towards the right method. For some reason, his solution produced an empty data frame, but I managed to figure out what he was trying to do and found a reasonable solution myself.

First of all, let's separate the GDP column from the flows dataset. I suspected this was necessary from the beginning, but I was confident I could filter it out while plotting. Turns out it's just easier to separate the two. Also, I'll normalise its values for later, because tens of billions…

```
df <- read.csv('stats.csv', header=T)
gdp <- data.frame(Year = df$Year, GDP = df$GDP/10000000000)
df <- within(df, rm(GDP))
```

The goal is to get the CI values side by side with their corresponding series. This was the code inside the `inner_join` in @lukeA answer. Once I took it apart, the path to the solution became clearer to me.

```
var_value <- df %>% 
    select(-ends_with("CI")) %>% 
    gather(var, value, -Year)

var_conf <- df %>% 
    select(Year, ends_with("CI")) %>% 
    setNames(sub("(.*)\\sCI$", "\\1", names(.))) %>% 
    gather(var, conf, -Year)

final.df = data.frame(var_value, conf = var_conf$conf)
```

Finally, @lukeA's ggplot code does produce the chart he shows.

```
ggplot(final.df, aes(
    x = Year, 
    y = value, 
    ymin = value - conf,
    ymax = value + conf, 
    color = var, 
    fill = var
    )) + 
geom_ribbon(alpha = .2) + 
geom_line()
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = 1991:2014, Total.inflow = c(329L, 268L, 
266L, 315L, 312L, 318L, 327L, 391L, 454L, 479L, 481L, 516L, 511L, 
589L, 567L, 596L, 574L, 590L, 567L, 591L, 566L, 498L, 526L, 632L
), Total.inflow.CI = c(23L, 20L, 19L, 23L, 22L, 25L, 27L, 27L, 
31L, 31L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 40L, 37L, 39L, 40L, 39L, 30L, 31L, 28L, 
27L, 29L, 36L), Total.outflow = c(-285L, -281L, -266L, -238L, 
-236L, -264L, -279L, -251L, -291L, -321L, -309L, -363L, -363L, 
-344L, -361L, -398L, -341L, -427L, -368L, -339L, -351L, -321L, 
-317L, -319L), Total.outflow.CI = c(23L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 
28L, 24L, 22L, 24L, 27L, 25L, 29L, 32L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 27L, 41L, 
22L, 20L, 22L, 20L, 19L, 22L), UK.inflow = c(93L, 81L, 75L, 91L, 
67L, 75L, 79L, 90L, 92L, 83L, 89L, 74L, 85L, 73L, 82L, 66L, 60L, 
71L, 82L, 84L, 69L, 73L, 70L, 68L), UK.inflow.CI = c(15L, 15L, 
12L, 16L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 12L, 16L, 
14L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 11L), UK.outflow = c(-142L, 
-146L, -141L, -112L, -130L, -141L, -140L, -121L, -133L, -151L, 
-150L, -172L, -184L, -189L, -175L, -200L, -158L, -159L, -130L, 
-125L, -133L, -131L, -125L, -128L), UK.outflow.CI = c(17L, 16L, 
16L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 19L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 22L, 
26L, 19L, 22L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 11L, 13L), EU.inflow = c(60L, 
49L, 48L, 53L, 60L, 74L, 70L, 75L, 64L, 55L, 54L, 57L, 58L, 128L, 
149L, 173L, 189L, 186L, 162L, 171L, 168L, 148L, 193L, 256L), 
    EU.inflow.CI = c(12L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 14L, 16L, 
    13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 19L, 21L, 18L, 
    17L, 20L, 25L), EU.outflow = c(-51L, -39L, -40L, -46L, -38L, 
    -50L, -51L, -52L, -57L, -55L, -50L, -54L, -47L, -45L, -56L, 
    -63L, -66L, -126L, -104L, -92L, -92L, -75L, -78L, -86L), 
    EU.outflow.CI = c(10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 9L, 13L, 
    12L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 31L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 
    12L, 12L, 15L), ROW.inflow = c(175L, 138L, 143L, 171L, 185L, 
    169L, 178L, 226L, 298L, 340L, 338L, 385L, 368L, 388L, 336L, 
    358L, 325L, 333L, 323L, 336L, 329L, 277L, 264L, 308L), ROW.inflow.CI = c(13L, 
    10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 24L, 22L, 
    31L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 24L), ROW.outflow = c(-91L, 
    -96L, -85L, -80L, -69L, -73L, -88L, -78L, -101L, -114L, -109L, 
    -136L, -133L, -109L, -129L, -135L, -117L, -142L, -134L, -122L, 
    -126L, -115L, -114L, -105L), ROW.outflow.CI = c(12L, 12L, 
    10L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 
    17L, 16L, 12L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 11L), GDP = c(1142797178130.51, 
    1179659529659.53, 1061388722255.55, 1140489745944.29, 1237561937825.47, 
    1306575663026.52, 1446444007858.55, 1537103345478.64, 1565408509949.85, 
    1554801028899.98, 1535942133294.95, 1680256294964.03, 1943025306122.45, 
    2297889051629.44, 2418941818181.82, 2588077276908.92, 2969733893557.42, 
    2793376838235.29, 2314577036921.64, 2403504326328.8, 2594904662714.31, 
    2630472981169.65, 2712296271989.99, 2990201431078.23)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Total.inflow", "Total.inflow.CI", "Total.outflow", "Total.outflow.CI", 
"UK.inflow", "UK.inflow.CI", "UK.outflow", "UK.outflow.CI", "EU.inflow", 
"EU.inflow.CI", "EU.outflow", "EU.outflow.CI", "ROW.inflow", 
"ROW.inflow.CI", "ROW.outflow", "ROW.outflow.CI", "GDP"), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks @nrussel. How do you produce that statement, so I can do it myself the next time?

Comment: You bet; calling `dput(df)` will produce the `structure(...)` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
download.file(
  "http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/88f76c7be8ade3a626f474f4857e16f8/stats.csv", 
  tf <- tempfile(), 
  method = "libcurl"
)
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_csv(tf)
inner_join(
  df %>% 
    select(-ends_with("CI")) %>% 
    gather(var, value, -Year),
  df %>% 
    select(Year, ends_with("CI")) %>% 
    setNames(sub("(.*)\\sCI$", "\\1", names(.))) %>% 
    gather(var, conf, -Year),
  by = c("Year", "var")
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Year, 
    y = value, 
    ymin = value - conf,
    ymax = value + conf, 
    color = var, 
    fill = var
  )) + 
  geom_ribbon(alpha = .2) + 
  geom_line()
```

gives you

[image]

(I'm using the latest development version of ggplot2)

Comment: Thanks. Could you comment your code a bit, explain what each part does?

Comment: What part in particular? I'd rather comment on unclear parts instead of writing an essay. ;-)

Comment: Even a general description of the process would do. I can work out what each call does, but I'm thinking maybe a couple of lines delineating the idea would make your answer more useful for future readers.

Comment: Sure. The above does the following: (1) Download CSV, (2) read it into `df`, (3) melt and cast `df` so that it has the columns Year, Variable, Value, +/-Confidence by joining two subsets (with "CI" and without "CI") of it, (4) plot ribbons and lines.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Any chance I could do the same without `tidyverse`? It seems some of its packages in CRAN are having troubles compiling… https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/169

Comment: Can you load the packages `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `ggplot2` instead? Should work, too. Another option could be `library(data.table);library(ggplot2);dt <- melt(fread(tf), id=1, measure=patterns("flow$", "CI$"), variable.name = "var", value.name = c("value", "conf"))` and then `ggplot(dt, aes(.........`.

Comment: `tidyr` depends on `tibble`, which is the one I can't compile. I'll try your alternative solution, thanks.

Comment: Hey – where does `patterns` come from?

Comment: `patterns` gets two regular expressions for separating columns containing values and confidence intervals by colum names (ending on "flow" and ending on "CI"). That was my first idea of doing it. Maybe there are better options though..

Comment: I understand it's from `data.table` but `could not find function "patterns"` is all I get. Alternatives?

Comment: Retry in a clean session and load only `data.table` and `ggplot2`.

Comment: Tried that, same deal.

Comment: `packageVersion("data.table")` says `‘1.9.6’` (or greater), right? In that case, I got to pass. Otherwise update `data.table`.

Comment: Yes, I'm on 1.9.6. Any chance to do this with `reshape2`? As far as I can tell, that works for me, I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: Well, to mimic the example from above, you could do `x <- reshape2::melt(df[, c("Year", grep("CI$", names(df), value = T))], 1, variable.name = "var", value.name = "conf");
levels(x$var) <- sub("(.*)\\sCI$", "\\1", levels(x$var));
y <- reshape2::melt(df[, c("Year", grep("flow$", names(df), value = T))], 1, variable.name = "var", value.name = "value");
df <- merge(x, y, by=c("Year", "var"))` and then `ggplot(df, aes(.....`

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot. After a lot of tinkering, I managed to get `tidyverse` to install and load. However, I ended up with empty dataframes, so I tried breaking up your original solution. Looks like the `inner_join` is the one producing an empty dataframe, and in fact I'm not sure how it's meant to do it since the values in the `variable` column are different (aka, contain or don't contain "CI"). I also tried your latest solution with `reshape2` and I still end up with an empty dataframe.

Comment: OK, I figured it out and I managed to find a decent solution. I'll add it to my question and mark your answer as accepted.